# Selection sort in single linked list without using swap

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to solve the selection sort in single linked list without using swap nodes. Using a temp list to store nodes and assign the current list with a new one

```
//my addlastnode function
void AddLastNODE(LIST &mylist, NODE *p)
{
//Check the list is empty or not
    if(isEmpty(mylist))
        mylist.pHead = mylist.pTail = p;
    else
        mylist.pTail->pNext = p;
        mylist.pTail = p;
}

void selectionSort(LIST &mylist)
{
//Initialize a temp list to store nodes 
    LIST mylisttemp;
    IntList(mylisttemp);
//Create node
    NODE *p;
    NODE *i;
//Create min node
    NODE *min;
//Check if list is empty or has one node
    if(mylist.pHead == mylist.pTail)
        return;
//Traverse the list till the last node
    for(p=mylist.pHead; p->pNext!=NULL && p!=NULL; p = p->pNext)
        {
            min=p;
                for(i=p->pNext; i!=NULL;i=i->pNext)
                {
////Find the smallest data in list
                    if(i->data < min->data)
                        min=i;
                }
////Add the smallest to a new list
                AddLastNODE(mylisttemp, min);
        }
//Fill the current list to the new list
    if(!isEmpty(mylisttemp))
    mylist = mylisttemp;
}
```

Comment: You can't just add the node in the new list without cleanly removing it from the old list : having the same node in two lists with only one chaining with `.next` is almost impossible.
Be careful that it is not so simple to remove a node in a list while iterating on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not reduce the list you are selecting nodes from: the selected node should be removed from it. To make that happen, you need a reference to the node *before* the selected node, so that you can rewire the list to exclude that selected node.

There is also a small issue in your `AddLastNODE` function: it does not force the tail node to have a null as `pNext` pointer. This may be a cause of errors when the function is called with a node that still has a non-null `pNext` pointer. Secondly, the indentation is off around the `else` block. It does not lead to a bug in this case, but still it is better to avoid the confusion:

```
void AddLastNODE(LIST &mylist, NODE *p)
{
    if(isEmpty(mylist))
        mylist.pHead = p;
    else
        mylist.pTail->pNext = p;
    mylist.pTail = p; // indentation!
    p->pNext = nullptr; // <--- better safe than sorry!
}
```

Then to the main algorithm. It is quite tedious to work with a *previous* node reference when looking for the node with the minimum value. It helps a bit when you temporarily make the input list *cyclic*:

```
void selectionSort(LIST &mylist) {
    if (mylist.pHead == mylist.pTail) return;
    // Make list temporarily cyclic
    mylist.pTail->pNext = mylist.pHead;

    LIST mytemplist;
    IntList(mytemplist);

    while (mylist.pHead != mylist.pTail) {
        // Select node:
        NODE * beforemin = mylist.pTail;
        for (NODE * prev = mylist.pHead; prev != mylist.pTail; prev = prev->pNext) {
            if (prev->pNext->data < beforemin->pNext->data) {
                beforemin = prev;
            }
        }
        NODE * min = beforemin->pNext;
        // Extract selected node:
        if (min == mylist.pTail) mylist.pTail = beforemin;
        if (min == mylist.pHead) mylist.pHead = min->pNext;
        beforemin->pNext = min->pNext;
        // And insert it:
        AddLastNODE(mytemplist, min);
    }
    // Move last remaining node
    AddLastNODE(mytemplist, mylist.pHead);
    // Copy back
    mylist = mytemplist;
}
```

As a side note: You might even want to *always* keep your list cyclic. This will mean some changes in other functions you may have, as there will be no `pNext` pointers that are null then.